# Regex remove the hyperlink from a column in pandas data frame (imported from csv)

Tags: python, html, regex

I read data from csv

`data_frame2 = pd.read_csv("search query.csv")`

`print(data_frame2['id'][0]')`

is

`HYPERLINK("https://something.com/resource/1308610617","1308610617")'`

what I have tried

```
data_frame2['id'] = data_frame2['id'].str.replace(r'https?://[^\s<>"]+|www\.[^\s<>"]+', "")
```

what I want to see is the last number for every row in that column.

```
1308610617
```

Comment: Are they all enclosed in `HYPERLINK function`?

Answer (score 1):

If the number is always at the last then this may help

```
data_frame2['id'] = data_frame2['id'].apply(lambda x:int(re.findall(r"[0-9]+$",x)[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture only the last numbers of the link location you can create a regex starting with a [`word boundary`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) follow by one or more digits (`\d+`) inside a capturing group. Then, use Pandas [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) function to return on the the desired parts. The capturing group will ensure that only the digits are returned by the extract function.

```py
import pandas as pd

regex = r'\b(\d+)",'

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['HYPERLINK("https://something.com/resource/1308610617","1308610617")']})

df['Num'] = df['id'].str.extract(regex)
print(df)
```

Output from *df*

```py
                                                                    id         Num

0  HYPERLINK("https://something.com/resource/1308610617","1308610617")  1308610617
```

Similarly, to capture the digits in the "friendly_name" part of the function you can replace the regex from the code above with `\b(\d+)"\)` (word boundary follow by one or more digits follow by double quotes and the character `)`).